# paper-input autofocus doesn't work inside router-outlet in an angular 2 component

Tags: angular, polymer, angular2-routing, paper-elements, autofocus

Lets say I have the following routes defined in my angular 2 application:

```
@RouteConfig([{
        component: FirstRouteComponent,
        name: "First",
        path: "/First",
        useAsDefault: true
    },
    {
        component: SecondRouteComponentComponent,
        name: "Second",
        path: "/Second"
    }])
    export class AppComponent {
    }
```

and in the FirstRouteComponent template I have:

```
<paper-input autofocus></paper-input>
```

When I navigate from the route "Second" to the route "First" (through some [routerLink] directive that I have on some a tag statically in the page)
the paper-input isn't focused. Oddly enough, if im already in route "First" and I refresh the page the paper input is successfully focused.

I have a feeling this has something to do with the way the angular 2 router dynamically insertes the paper-input into the dom, and how polymer uses the autofocus but I cant point out the problem. I might be wrong though and this issue is "weird" because I haven't had any sort of problems with passing any other parameters to polymer components (including paper-input) in my components before now.

Thanks in advance for any assistance :)

Comment: It looks like `autofocus` is passed directly to the inner `<input>`. Does a native `<input>` exhibit the same problem with `autofocus`? If so, the issue might be outside of Polymer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
<paper-input #autofocus></paper-input>
in AppComponent:

import { AfterViewInit, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';
 export class AppComponent implements  AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChildren('autofocus') fc;
   ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.fc.first.nativeElement.focus();
    }
}
```